# Can OpenGL ES help in this game?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, effects

I am learning OpenGL ES and I have setup the environment. I believe the best way to learn things is to grab a dummy project and start working on it. So what I plan to do is...

[Flare on a parachute http://goo.gl/8vN4R](http://goo.gl/8vN4R)

Now I want this parachute to be created in OpenGL ES with sparkling effect at its tip. The sparkling effect must be shiny and animating like it's really sparkling. And the whole parachute would be moving down from top of the screen slowly and slightly fluctuating its position.

Please tell me if this is what I can do using OpenGL ES or I should use some other framework for fast development.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using OpenGL as the underlying graphics technology it is beneficial to think of the problem in terms of what OpenGL is good at.

As with any other 3D API, the focus is primarily on fast transformation and rasterisation of primitives like triangle, often with texture maps and in some cases programmable shaders.

Your scenario can be modeled in two parts:
 - draw a 2D quad (or pair of triangles) which you translate and rotate according to the way you want it to move;
 - the sparkling effect can be a set of quads with an animated texture or which rotate in place to give local motion to things.

Another approach for the "sparkling" could be to have a particle system attached which sends off sparks and particles into the air.